# Not returning any result while retrieving data from oracle database using vb6, please help me to locate the error

Tags: oracle, vb6

When i check the result set. record count it returns -1 and while checking the recordset.EOF it returns true, thus the result set does not contain any value.

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL

Private Sub cmd_login_Click()
    Dim pass As String
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=localhost;User Id=ams;Password=krishnan;"
    con.Open
    strSQL = "Select passwrd from ams.login_details where username = 'Admin'"
    rs.Open strSQL, con
    If Not (rs.EOF) Then    
        If rs("passwrd") = txt_pass.Text Then
            MsgBox rs("passwrd")
        End If
    End If
    rs.Close
    con.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the reference Microsoft ActiveX dataobject 2.6 liabrary

Comment: try using UPPER(username) = 'ADMIN'

Comment: Nope it's not working :(

Comment: Is the query working when it is run at SQL prompt? Is it returning any rows? Please add this details to your question

Answer (score 0):

I forget to commit the statements in Oracle Sql Developer that's why not data was fetched from the database, When i executed the commit statement, it's working fine.